# Where to use SAS Token in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, azure-storage

I'm making an Android app that will connect to an Azure Storage Account to save information in a table. When I run the app in the simulator, and press the button that opens the page that connects to the database I get an exception stating "Shared Key is not supported using the PCL. Please use a SAS token."

So I followed the steps to generate a SAS token but I'm not sure what to do with the string. Can anyone suggest where I should place the string?

```
namespace UndergroundSports
{
[Activity]          
public class austinBowlingSignUpPage : Activity    
{
    protected override async void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.austinBowlingSignUpPage);

        EditText austinBowlingFullNameEntry = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.austinBowlingFullNameEntry);

        EditText austinBowlingEmailEntry = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.austinBowlingEmailEntry);

        Button austinBowlingSubmitButton = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.austinBowlingSignUpButton);

        string sas = "https://undergroundathletes.blob.core.windows.net/underground-container?sv=2015-04-05&sr=c&sig=Gcgc28K%2B\nc6uQk9pkHRAotshR7zEU%3D&se=2016-04-20T18%3A13%3A31Z&sp=rwdl";

        string connectionString = 

            "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;" +
            "AccountName=My_Account_Name;" +
            "AccountKey=My_Account_Key";

                    CloudStorageAccount storageaccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse (connectionString);

        CloudTableClient tableClient = storageaccount.CreateCloudTableClient ();

        CloudTable austinBowlingAthletes = tableClient.GetTableReference ("austinBowlingAthletesTable");

        await austinBowlingAthletes.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

austinBowlingSubmitButton.Click += async (sender, e) => {

            austinBowlingAthlete austinBowlingAthlete1 = new austinBowlingAthlete();
            austinBowlingAthlete1.fullname = austinBowlingFullNameEntry.ToString();
            austinBowlingAthlete1.email = austinBowlingEmailEntry.ToString();

            TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(austinBowlingAthlete1);

            await austinBowlingAthletes.ExecuteAsync(insertOperation);


        };
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `StorageCredentials` based on the SAS token, use the credentials to create `CloudStorageAccount` and call `CreateCloudTableClient` on the storage account to get `CloudTableClient`:

```
StorageCredentials creds = new StorageCredentials(sas);
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(creds, null, null, tableStorageUri, null);
CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
CloudTable austinBowlingAthletes = tableClient.GetTableReference("austinBowlingAthletesTable");
```

Everything else stays the same.

Check this example: [Teal (Azure Storage sample for Xamarin)](https://github.com/conceptdev/xamarin-samples/blob/master/Azure/Teal/Table.xaml.cs)

Comment: Where in the Azure Portal can I find the Uri that I use in tableStorageUri?

Comment: I think I found it...it's under "Table Service Endpoint" on the Tables Blade, right? With the format: https://storageaccountname.table.core.windows.net/

Comment: @msloan11: I think so